# Billdesk payment gateway integration

Tags: php, payment-gateway

I am developing a website in php and I want to integrate bill desk payment gateway in it. So that i can make transactions from Indian bank's debit card & credit cards.
 So I need help how to integrate bill desk payment gateway in my website.

Answer (score 0):

Just signup billdesk. You will get the documents for the integration with all technologies. You can get the sample snippet as well.